# {amsmath} \settasks \begintask multiple errors generated by \end{task}

Tags: amsmath, enumerate, tasks

OP edited below to show resolution of enumeration issue (h/t @egreg). But there are several error messages generated by `\end{tasks}/`

Your assistance is much appreciated!

mwe:

````
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{caption} 
% allows captions in minipage envir
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{framed} %box para
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\everymath{\displaystyle}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % removes paragraph indentation

\pagestyle{head}
\header{Unit 9 Assignment: Lesson 4-7 Part 1 - Quadratic Formula Practice}
       {}
       {02/13/2023} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
  %\makebox[\textwidth]%{Name:\enspace\hrulefill}\par
  \vspace{4mm}
  \fbox{\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-4\fboxsep-4\fboxrule}{
    \textbf {Use the Quadratic Formula to solve each equation. Write answers in 2 forms: (1) integer or simplified radical (2) decimal approximation.}
    %\par
    %\bigskip

  }}}\par
  \vspace{0.5mm}
}

\begin{document}
\pagetop

\newcommand*{\qf}{$x=\frac{-(b) \pm\sqrt{(b)^2-4(a)(c)}}{2(a)}$}

\settasks{after-item-skip=5em,
          after-skip=2cm,
          label-width=2em,
          item-indent=3em,
          label=(\arabic*),
          column-sep=2em
          }

\begin{tasks}(2)
%Prob #1
\task $-x^2+7x-3=0$
\\\\
Divide by $-1$ to cancel $-1$ on leading coefficient.
\\\\
$x^2-7x+3=0$\\
\\\\
\begin{aligned}
$x&=\frac{-(7)\pm\sqrt{(-7)^2-4(1)(3)}}{2(1)}$
\\\\
$&=\frac{-7\pm\sqrt{7^2-12}}{2}$
\\\\
$&=\frac{-7\pm\sqrt{37}}{2}$
\end{aligned}
%Prob #2
\task $x^2+6x=10$
\\\\
\qf


\end{tasks}
\end{document}```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiM1c.jpg
````

Comment: We can't debug. Anyway the requested labels should be obtained with `label=[*]`

Comment: @egreg  replacing ```counter-format=(tsk[1])``` with ```label=[*]``` solved the enumeration problem. However, if I want Arabic numbers instead of alpha letters, what is the syntax? You are always very generous in providing assistance. Many thanks!

Comment: `label=[\arabic*]`, maybe?

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the suggestion. ```label=[\arabic*] did not  change the alpha numbering.  Is there a more standard way to horizontally enumerate a 2 column maths problem set like mine?

Comment: @egreg Your fix worked. Question marked "solved". Can you possibly assist with ```end{tasks}``` errors?

Comment: Your code cannot be compiled.

Comment: @egreg With the aforementioned log errors, I am able to get it compiled in overleaf. Why would that be the case?  Would you possibly have time to take this thread into chat so I can email you screen shot of compiled pdf? I understand you've already invested substantial time in resolving this. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want something like

```
label-format={[\arabic*]}
```

but you also need some other adjustments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}[
  label={[\arabic*]},
  label-width=16pt,
  label-align=right,
  label-offset=6pt,
](2)
\task $-x^2+7x-3=0$
\task $x^2+6x=10$
\task $2x^2=4x+3$
\task $4x^2+81=36x$
\task $4m^4n^3 \cdot 4m^2n^3$
\task $-4m^3n^4 \cdot 2m$
\task $4nm^0 \cdot 4m^4n^2$
\task $-4a^0b^2 \cdot ba^3$
\task $a^4b^2c^3 \cdot 2a^2b^4$
\task $-4zx^4y^4 \cdot -3x^3y^0z^4$
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]